# How to create an image in php

Tags: php, image

I have been trying to create an image from a file path but the resulting image consists of huge noise.

What I have done so far:-

```
function createImage($imageFile) {
  $response = '';
  if (!empty($imageFile)) {
    if (file_exists($imageFile)) {
      switch (strtolower(pathinfo($imageFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))) {
        case 'jpeg':
        case 'jpg':
          header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
          $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFile);
          imagejpeg($img);
          break;
        case 'png':
          header('Content-Type: image/png');
          $img = imagecreatefrompng($imageFile);
          imagepng($img);
          break;
        case 'gif':
          header('Content-Type: image/gif');
          $img = imagecreatefromgif($imageFile);
          imagegif($img);
          break;
      }
      imagedestroy($img);
    } else {
      $response = "Not exists";
    }
  }
  echo $response;
}
```

The actual image is:
[image]

I got the following result:
[image]

Expected image is:-
[image: n]

I would like to generate the same image that you saw in the actual image. Can someone help me?

Comment: Noted @GrumpyCrouton - I had a coffee malfunction.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue. I tried your code with a couple of jpeg images and they all look correct. Have you tried with other images? Does it happen to all, or is it just this one image this happens with?

Comment: @magnus, My image size is below 5Kb.

Comment: I tested one that's 4kB and one that's 4mB and both worked.

Comment: which version of PHP?

Comment: Thanks for checking. Could you please try the same image that I displayed here

Comment: @Marcos, PHP Version 7.1

Comment: That was the first I tried. But the one here is not the same as the one you have. When you upload images on imgur, it's likely that they optimize the images, which could change them (stripping meta data, removing color profiles etc). Is there anywhere I can download the same one you're using?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, Image link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DSVzafFP3AZi9QTMeNi0DiJQRAu3-Pqb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Make sure there is no extra data can be output by the rest of your script, and output is not altered in any way (e.g. over output buffering). Can you provide the full script which produces the problem?

Comment: That one worked as well. Do as @AterLux suggests and make sure no other output happens. You can even add an `exit;` before your `break;` in your switch/case to make sure there's no other output after.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, It worked. I got the expected result after adding exit; before break; Thank you.